# XCODE 13.2.1 Не компилирует приложение на устройство

Tags: swift, xcode

приложение отлично работает на симуляторе, но при попытке запуска на реальном устройстве падает в ошибку

```
Command PhaseScriptExecution failed with a nonzero exit code
```

Насколько я понимаю, проблема в связке ключей.
Нашел ответ на eng версии стака, ответ звучал так:

```
I had that problem and Xcode failed to compile on the device, but on simulator, it worked fine.

I solved with these steps:

1 Open keychain access.
2 Lock the 'login' keychain.
3 Unlock it, enter your PC account password.
4 Clean Project in the product menu.
5 Build it Again.
And after that everything works fine
```

Но из-за скудного английского и корявого переводчика, плюс отсутствие нормальных знаний, я не особо понимаю, что он именно имел ввиду.
В связке нашел раздел "Apple Development", но в нем пусто, может дело в этом, однако, как туда добавить ключи я тоже не нашел.
Буду рад любой помощи!
Спасибо:)

Answer (score 0):

И так, в поисках решения проблемы, я забрел на зарубежный, не пойми какой форум. Там проблема была другой, но все же, решило мою.
Порядок действий для сброса нашей связки:

1. Первое, заходим в настройки xcode и удаляем привязанный аккаунт
2. Дальше наш путь лежит к приложению связка ключей, там мы переходим в
   настройки (в верхнем баре тык на "связка ключей" - "настройки") и
   смело нажимаем сбросить связку ключей по умолчанию
3. После этого нам вылезет сообщение, дескать не удалось подключиться к
   айклауду и выполняем привязку связки ключей по новой(просто много
   раз вводим все пароли, которые у нас попросят)
4. Отлично, мы на финишной прямой, теперь после привязки, открываем
   xcode и указываем в настройках нашего приложения, нового
   разработчика
   И после всех этих манипуляций, я спокойно открыл приложение на своем айфоне!